# Java chatbot -- code not working as intended

Tags: java, chatbot

I have the following code for a chat bot work in progress. However, it does not work as intended. When I run the debugger, it shows that "bye", for some bizarre reason, keeps getting assigned to "keyword". Logically, everything looks like it should work as intended. But apparently not. Any help is appreciated. I'm rather new to Java programming.

```
public class Chatbot {


    public Chatbot( )
    {
    }

    /*
     * Generates a variety of responses, based on what the user has stated
     */
    public static void respond( String statement )
    {        
        // use the findKeyword method to check for various cases of user statements
        if( statement.length() == 0 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Please say something :)" );
        }

        else if( findKeyword( statement, "hi" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "hello" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "hey" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "hiya" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "heya" ) > 0 )
            {
                System.out.println( "Hello to you too!" );
            }

        else if( findKeyword( statement, "how are you" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "hows it going" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "howre you" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "how ya doing" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "yo wassup" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "hey whats up" ) > 0 || 
                 findKeyword( statement, "whats up" ) > 0 )
            {
                System.out.println( "I'm good, how are you?" );
            }
    }



    /*
     * findKeyword method, returns either a 0 or a 1
     * @ 0 -- keyword not found
     * @ 1 -- keyword found
     */
    public static int findKeyword( String statement, String keyword )
    {

                // This is in case the keyword is not in the statement at all
        if( !statement.contains( keyword ) )
        {
            return 0;
        }


        int position = statement.toLowerCase().indexOf( keyword.toLowerCase() );        // position of the keyword in the statement
        statement = " " + statement.toLowerCase().replaceAll( "\'\",.?", "") + " ";                   // the purpose of this statement is to allow for us to search for specific phrases w/ spaces before and after the keyword

        String sub = statement.substring( position, position + keyword.length() + 1 );  // isolates the keyword with 1 character before and after

        String charBeforeKeyword = sub.substring( 0, 1 );                               // the character before the keyword
        String charAfterKeyword = sub.substring( sub.length() - 1, sub.length() );      // the character after the keyword



        /*
         * Now, we check to see if the characters we isolated before are letters; if they are        * 
         * @ If they are letters...then our keyword is part of a bigger word (e.g. if we searched for "success" and it brought us "successful"
         * @ If they are not letters, then we have found our keyword with punctuation and/or spaces before/after it
         */
        if( (charBeforeKeyword.compareTo( "a" ) < 0 || charBeforeKeyword.compareTo( "z" ) > 0 )
                && (charAfterKeyword.compareTo( "a" ) < 0 || charAfterKeyword.compareTo( "z" ) > 0 ))
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;  

    }


}



import java.util.Scanner;

public class Execute 
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {   
        // Variables and Objects
        Chatbot bot = new Chatbot();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String statement = "";

        // Prompt and get the user's first input
        System.out.println( "Type text to start chatting!" );
        statement = input.nextLine();

        // While the user doesn't say goodbye or some other form of it, respond to user and then get their next response
        while( bot.findKeyword( statement, "bye" ) != 1 &&
               bot.findKeyword( statement, "cya" ) != 1 &&
               bot.findKeyword( statement, "goodbye" ) != 1 &&
               bot.findKeyword( statement, "gtg" ) != 1 )
        {
            bot.respond( statement );
            statement = input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println( "Goodbye!" );




    }

}
```

Comment: Read how to post a [mcve] and then edit your question.

Comment: You can't say "it doesn't work as intended" but not tell us how it is intended to work. Tell us what happens AND what you expect to happen, or there is nothing we can do. Give an example input output that you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,Please read the javadoc of `substring`.

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1

Based on your logic, you have to modify

```
 String sub = statement.substring( position, position + keyword.length() + 1 );
```

to

```
String sub = statement.substring( position, position + keyword.length() + 2 );
```

2, No need to use static method in `Chatbot` since you have created the instance of `Chatbot`.

3, Remember to close the `Scanner` when you don't use it any more.

See the updated code as below:

```
public class Chatbot {


    public Chatbot( )
    {
    }

    /*
     * Generates a variety of responses, based on what the user has stated
     */
    public void respond( String statement )
    {        
        // use the findKeyword method to check for various cases of user statements
        if( statement.length() == 0 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Please say something :)" );
        }

        else if( findKeyword( statement, "hi" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "hello" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "hey" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "hiya" ) > 0 ||
            findKeyword( statement, "heya" ) > 0 )
            {
                System.out.println( "Hello to you too!" );
            }

        else if( findKeyword( statement, "how are you" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "hows it going" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "howre you" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "how ya doing" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "yo wassup" ) > 0 ||
                 findKeyword( statement, "hey whats up" ) > 0 || 
                 findKeyword( statement, "whats up" ) > 0 )
            {
                System.out.println( "I'm good, how are you?" );
            }
    }



    /*
     * findKeyword method, returns either a 0 or a 1
     * @ 0 -- keyword not found
     * @ 1 -- keyword found
     */
    public int findKeyword( String statement, String keyword )
    {

                // This is in case the keyword is not in the statement at all
        if( !statement.contains( keyword ) )
        {
            return 0;
        }


        int position = statement.toLowerCase().indexOf( keyword.toLowerCase() );        // position of the keyword in the statement
        statement = " " + statement.toLowerCase().replaceAll( "\'\",.?", "") + " ";                   // the purpose of this statement is to allow for us to search for specific phrases w/ spaces before and after the keyword

        String sub = statement.substring( position, position + keyword.length() + 2 );  // isolates the keyword with 1 character before and after

        String charBeforeKeyword = sub.substring( 0, 1 );                               // the character before the keyword
        String charAfterKeyword = sub.substring( sub.length() - 1, sub.length());      // the character after the keyword



        /*
         * Now, we check to see if the characters we isolated before are letters; if they are        * 
         * @ If they are letters...then our keyword is part of a bigger word (e.g. if we searched for "success" and it brought us "successful"
         * @ If they are not letters, then we have found our keyword with punctuation and/or spaces before/after it
         */
        if( (charBeforeKeyword.compareTo( "a" ) < 0 || charBeforeKeyword.compareTo( "z" ) > 0 )
                && (charAfterKeyword.compareTo( "a" ) < 0 || charAfterKeyword.compareTo( "z" ) > 0 ))
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;  

    }


}
```

And also the `Execute` class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Execute 
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {   
        // Variables and Objects
        Chatbot bot = new Chatbot();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String statement = "";

        // Prompt and get the user's first input
        System.out.println( "Type text to start chatting!" );
        statement = input.nextLine();

        // While the user doesn't say goodbye or some other form of it, respond to user and then get their next response
        while( bot.findKeyword( statement, "bye" ) != 1 &&
               bot.findKeyword( statement, "cya" ) != 1 &&
               bot.findKeyword( statement, "goodbye" ) != 1 &&
               bot.findKeyword( statement, "gtg" ) != 1 )
        {
            bot.respond( statement );
            statement = input.nextLine();
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println( "Goodbye!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that close method is pretty darn important, huh? Completely changed how my program works.

Comment: Actually, the +2 isn't necessary, is it? Suppose you have the String "ABCD" with keyword "BC", thus position = 1, length of the keyword = 2, position + length + 1 = 4, which encloses the character after the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the "words" initialized in a String word

example

```
public class Chatbot {


    public Chatbot( )
    {
      String hi= "hi"
      String hello= "Hello"
      String hey= "Hey"
      String hiya= "Hiya"
      String heya= "Heya"
      String n;



    }

    /*
     * Generates a variety of responses, based on what the user has stated
     */
    public static void respond( String statement )
    {        
        // use the findKeyword method to check for various cases of user statements
        if( n = sc1.next()== "")
        {
            System.out.println( "Please say something :)" );
        }

        else if( findKeyword( statement, hi ) ||
            findKeyword( statement, hello )  ||
            findKeyword( statement,hey ) ||
            findKeyword( statement,  hiya)  ||
            findKeyword( statement, heya) )
            {
                System.out.println( "Hello to you too!" );
            }
```

that's my guess though...